# The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter

Tags: json, deserialization

I am creating an array in my jquery code then am calling stringify to make it as json data and then am calling a service that receives an object , but unfortunately I am getting this error , and this error is caused by the fact that my object consists of array properties , I have the same code and it's all working fine when my object is only strings and numbers....this is a part of my object

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class ImagesEditInfo
{

    [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
    public int[] ImageIds
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

}

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your service look like and could you provide some sample requests?

I approximately use this for service calls

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: serviceURL,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ serviceParameterName: javascriptObject }),
        success: successFunction,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

in your case your service method would have to be something like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = serviceURL, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public string methodName(ImagesEditInfo serviceParameterName) { }
```

Comment: [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "ImagesEdit")]
        public string UpdateImages(ImagesEditInfo ImagesInfo)
        {
}

       $.ajax({
            url: "Service URL",
            dataType: 'json'
            type: 'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: 'post-data',--This is the stringified object.
            success: function () {
                //Do nothing on success
                return;
            },

Comment: and this is how do i create the object

var serviceData = { ImageIds: imageids, ImageNames: imagenames, ImageDescriptions: imagedescriptions, imagetags: ImageTags, IsDownloadable: isdownloadables, IsCommentable: iscommentables };
        serviceData = {ImagesInfo : serviceData};

Comment: @user510336 Is the stringified object the equivalent of `JSON.stringify({ImagesInfo: serviceData})`? Also: do all of your properties in your DataContract have getters and setters?

Comment: anthony yes , and yes all the properties are the exact of the object sample i provided.

Comment: shall there be any difference when my object consists of arrays?? cause I am using the same code exactly to deserialize another objects and it's working fine , but this one is a problem cause it's all arrays.

Comment: Sorry It's working now , I was having a mistake in sending the object to .net